# Like Sudarshana Chakra, do any other weapons have a form?

Tags: identification-request, weapon, sudarshana-chakra

The Sudarshana Chakra is said to have a form somewhat:

[image]

Like the Sudharshana Chakra, do any other weapons also have an anthropomorphic form? What, if any, scriptures mention this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**vishnudharmottara purana ch 85**](https://archive.org/details/vishnudharmottar031493mbp/page/n128/mode/1up) :

> *On the right should be the **goddess Gada, in the shape of a woman** with a thin middle, with beautiful eyes, adorned with all ornaments
> and lovely. The goddess should carry a chamara looking at the lord of
> the god of gods. The right hand of the god should be placed on her
> head.*
>
> *Placed on the left side should be **Chakra** with a big belly, furnished with all ornaments, with eyes wide open (as) in dancing. He
> should carry a chamara and should be engaged at looking at the god.
> The left hand of the god should be placed on the head of that
> (chakra).*
>
> *In place of gada, **the pestle** (should be represented) and in place of chakra, the **plough**. **They should be endowed with the forms of
> men**, furnished with beauty and with thin middle.*
>
> *In place of the wheel should be the **bow** and in place of the club the **arrow** and the **plough and spear should be shown similar to
> them (i.e. assuming human bodies)**.*
>
> *In place of the wheel should be the **sword**. The **personified shield** should have the appearance of chakra personified (but) **the
> sword is rendered as a man of high stature**. Their beautiful real
> forms in the shape of weapons should be partially shown on the heads
> of chakra and others, oh descendant of Yadu.*

Answer (score 2):

Sri Vishnu has the Kaumodaki mace or gada as an ayudhapurush ( anthropomorphic weapon). The power in the mace  which was female, (Gadadevi), denoted the power of Time, or intelligence, life force, discipline.
The inner meaning is that to lead a life as enjoined by the divine scriptures gives greatest powers.

In  Garuda Purana,Chapter 13, the Kaumodaki is mentioned in the Vishnu Panjaram

Take up thy club Kaumodaki, O lotus-navelled deity, salutation unto thee.